# Ruby on Rails 1 系 のコードを 5系 へアップグレードできますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Ruby on Rails 1 系 で動作していたプロジェクトが複数あります**
・現在、動作していません(コードのみあります)
・DBは「.sqlite3」のプロジェクトと、「PostgreSQL」のプロジェクトがありますが、これからはMySQLで統一したいです

**質問**

- 1 系 のRailsプロジェクトを、5系 へアップグレードできますか？
- それとも、5系 として1から作成し直した方が早い(と思いますか)？

※そもそも1 系 のコードを(確認のため)動作させることは、(現実的に考えて)可能？？

Comment: `現在動作していません`が「単に検証していないだけ」なのか「試してみたけど正常に動かなかった」なのかがいまいち読み取れません。

Comment: まだ動作検証していません。多分、多大な労力が必要だと思います。Rails は変化が激しいと聞いているので、(例え動作させることができたとしても)1系Railsからアップグレードできなければ本末転倒かなと不安になりました。また1系の動作検証を行った場合、その知識は今後何らかの役に立つことはあるのか、と疑問に思い質問しました

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rails4.0がリリースされた頃に他人が作った1系のアプリをメンテした経験があります。
結論から言うと、5系で一から作成した方が絶対早いと思いますよ。

そもそも、1系のアプリを動かすまでが大変です。
macにruby1.8をインストールするのも苦労しましたし・・・
bundlerの無い時代ですから、各種gemを探してきてインストールするのも大変だったと思います。
（ネイティブビルドが必要なgemなら一層大変）

仮にアップグレードするにしても、基本的には1系->2系->3系・・・と順を追うのが定石ですし、
テストコードが無かったとしたら、正しくアップグレードできたかの動作確認も大変でしょうし。

アップグレード案は何一つメリットは無いと思います。

Comment: 4系であれば、頑張れる気するので、頑張れなくなる境目はどこだろう、と、なんとなく疑問に思ったりしてます。